# Unable to use permute nd array in matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, transpose

X is 4d array of size - 50000x3x32x32. I want to transpose the 4d array into 50000x32x32x3.

```
Y = permute(X, [1 4 2 3]);
```

But, the dimension of Y is still 50000x32x3x32. But it should 50000x32x32x3. Can somebody help me what is the problem here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try : `[1 3 4 2]`.

Comment: Thanks. I should think in the other way.

Comment: You are right, the [online help](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) doesn't explain the direction of the `order` parameter at all.

Comment: Could one of you please post the answer? pranavanuom @rahnema1

Comment: @CrisLuengo An answer is posted. Unfortunately you can't accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the definition from the [online documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

> `B = permute(A,order)` rearranges the dimensions of A so that they are in the order specified by the vector order.

We can use size to get dimensions of an array:

`S = size(X)`

```
S =

[50000 3 32 32]
```

We want to reorder the vector of dimensions so that it becomes `[50000 32 32 3]`. Then we should set the order as `[1 3 4 2]`.

```
order = [1 3 4 2];
S_result = S(order)

S_result =
[50000 32 32 3]
```

Comment: Is this not what OP did?

Comment: OP did `[1 4 2 3]`. I have answered in the comment but a user asked me to post an explained  answer.

Comment: Sorry, it's very late here. This is a really nice answer. +1